# Why when I send the "è" character through an AJAX GET Request to an input param of a Spring MVC controller method it arrives wrong?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC application that use Thymeleaf for the views and I have the following problem  when I send some strings by an AJAX request (I don't know if it could depend by thymeleaf or from something else).

So, into my view I have this **TextArea** tag in which the user insert some text:

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; text-align: center;">
    <label for="notaCorrente">Inserire una nuova nota negli appunti:</label>
    <textarea id="notaCorrente" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
</div> 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="aggiungiAppunti()">Salva</button>
```

Then I have a JavaScript function that send the inserted data to the controller performing a GET AJAX request:

```
function aggiungiAppunti() {
    console.log("INTO aggiungiAppunti()");
    //alert("INTO aggiungiAppunti()");

    var testoNotaCorrente = $('#notaCorrente').val();

    alert("NOTA CORRENTE: " + testoNotaCorrente);

    var message = 'Sei sicuro di voler salvare questi appunti?';

    mostraConferma(message, function (){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "aggiungiAppunti",
            data : { 
                'testoNotaCorrente': testoNotaCorrente
            },
            contentType:"application/json"
        }).done(function(principal) {
            replaceFragment($('#situazioniDocumentali'),principal);
            inizializzazioneGestioneValidazione();
        }).error(function(error) {
            showErrorMessage("errore");
        }); 
    });

}
```

And finally I have this controller method that handle this AJAX Request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aggiungiAppunti", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String aggiungiAppunti(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale, @RequestParam("testoNotaCorrente") String testoNotaCorrente) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("INTO aggiungiAppunti(), testo nota corrente: " +  testoNotaCorrente);

    .....................................................................   
    .....................................................................       
    DO SOMETHING
    .....................................................................       
    .....................................................................               

    return "gestioneValidazione/gestioneValidazione :: situazioniDocumentali";
}
```

So this method receive the **@RequestParam("testoNotaCorrente") String testoNotaCorrente** input parameter that represent.

It works fine except that for some text characters.

For example if the user insert into the textbox the **è** character, when it is sended to the controller method through the AJAX Request it is received (into the **testoNotaCorrente** input parameter) as **Ã¨** as not as the original character (it does similar behavior also for other characters).

Why I obtain this behavior? I think that there are some charset\enconding problem when the data is trasmitted but I can't understand what is the problem. What am I mising? How can I try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Update to your AJAX call utf-8 encoding with:

```
contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

Or in your code:

```
function aggiungiAppunti() {
    console.log("INTO aggiungiAppunti()");
    //alert("INTO aggiungiAppunti()");

    var testoNotaCorrente = $('#notaCorrente').val();

    alert("NOTA CORRENTE: " + testoNotaCorrente);

    var message = 'Sei sicuro di voler salvare questi appunti?';

    mostraConferma(message, function (){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "aggiungiAppunti",
            data : { 
                'testoNotaCorrente': testoNotaCorrente
            },
            contentType:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        }).done(function(principal) {
            replaceFragment($('#situazioniDocumentali'),principal);
            inizializzazioneGestioneValidazione();
        }).error(function(error) {
            showErrorMessage("errore");
        }); 
    });

}
```

Comment: I have added the charset=UTF-8 on the contentType definition o the AJAX call but I still obtain always the same result. The value is wrong when it cames as input parameter of my controller method

Comment: Check what is the browser sending with ajax request.